# How to replace android phone call reciveve application

Tags: android

I am planning to replace the phone call receive app with an app that display time and cost of incoming call (in roaming), Along with the other details.

I can only replace the screen which shows pick up the phone, but I need to replace the screen after picking up the phone.

Any help is welcome

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean exactly. Better explanation maybe?

Comment: when you get a call, there is a screen which shows option to pickup the phone once you pick up the phone there is another screen which shows call detail (dialpad, headset, etc option) s. I plan to replace that screen with an app